# A verb that means to signal or to signpost

Tags: single-word-requests

If someone is really overt with their intentions, you could say they're _____ their intentions. Signalling and signposting kind of work, but there's a word that's eluding me which fits this usage exactly.

The connotation I'm looking for is to *make really obvious* or *call attention to* especially with regards to how the intentions (or other noun) change with time.

Comment: How does this not deserve to be closed because it meets the criteria of [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity)? It's just a guess-me thesaurus hunt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word I was looking for is actually **telegraph** (memory finally clicked).

[Definition at Dictionary.com:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/telegraph) 
*Informal.* to divulge or indicate unwittingly (one's intention, next offensive move, etc.), as to an opponent or to an audience; broadcast.

Answer (score 1):

They are *parading* their intentions. From [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parade):

> **parade** ... [verb] [transitive] 2.1 Display (something) in order to impress or attract attention.  ‘he paraded his knowledge’

'Display' also works, but has perhaps lost punchiness through overuse of the slightly broadened sense.

'Manifest' and 'vaunt' don't work too well here in my opinion.

Comment: Hmm, that has more a connotation of arrogance, which is not what I'm going for.

Comment: But you used the word 'blatant', which [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blatant) states << You use 'blatant' to describe something bad that is done in an open or very obvious way. >>.

Comment: But open and obvious doesn't have to mean arrogant as well.

Comment: The word I was looking for is actually **telegraph** (memory finally clicked). But since I mis-remembered its meaning (unwittingly revealed rather than blatantly), I'm accepting this answer as it better fits my original post.

Comment: Just change 'blatant' for 'overt', unaccept this answer (I prefer 'telegraph'), post your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 1):

- They are **flagging** their intentions.

That's the most idiomatic word I heard in this context.

Answer (score 1):

The word that best fits here is I would say:

## [Demonstrating](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/demonstrate)

> To show or make make something clear - Cambridge.

So your sentence could read:

***They're demonstrating their intentions.***

Here are examples of the usage in a wide variety of different contexts:

> Here the reader seemed to be *demonstrating intentions*, expertise and a
> level of public concern that was appropriate for someone of his age.

-- [Analysing Political Speeches](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kk4dBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=%22demonstrating%20intentions%22&source=bl&ots=L23uLwxU8q&sig=gDM-EtftDl7_0w6sONAYnJ-95jo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-g__fm-vXAhVbFMAKHZLMARcQ6AEIPzAH#v=onepage&q=%22demonstrating%20intentions%22&f=false): Rhetoric, Discourse and Metaphor - Jonathan Charteris-Black.

> ... deictic elements depend for their success on contextual facts and
> *demonstrating intention*...

-- [Linguistics Today](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oo6YQRY7RBQC&pg=PT218&lpg=PT218&dq=%22demonstrating%20intentions%22&source=bl&ots=py9iv10Cod&sig=FPNKlo43hpkuKD0Xw60KAGGTS0o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-g__fm-vXAhVbFMAKHZLMARcQ6AEISDAK#v=onepage&q=%22demonstrating%20intentions%22&f=false): Facing a Greater Challenge - P. G. J. van Sterkenburg.

> Finally, a section for the "Demonstration of Intentionality" is
> developed by: (1) proposing the theoretical necessity for
> *demonstrating intentions*...

-- [Culturicide, Resistance, and Survival of the Lakota](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=O1i4AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=%22demonstrating%20intentions%22&source=bl&ots=KWhWyLI1iP&sig=e_lAwhzO22jBFhzOcEYer6wDuv0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-g__fm-vXAhVbFMAKHZLMARcQ6AEIQjAI#v=onepage&q=%22demonstrating%20intentions%22&f=false): (Sioux Nation) - James V. Fenelon.

> ...evidences critical and analytical understanding and that the pupils
> are d*emonstrating intentions*.

-- [Art revision support document](https://www.dormston.dudley.sch.uk/assets/Word-Document-Uploads/Art-revision-support.pdf) - Dormston Secondary School.

Answer (score 0):

The word I would use is **broadcast**:

> tell (something) to many people; make widely known.
>   *"we don't want to broadcast our unhappiness to the world"*
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/broadcast)</sub>